# Break up my application.handlebars into separate templates using Ember.js and Ember.Router

Tags: ember.js

I'm building a front-end (on top of Ruby on Rails) using `ember.js` and the `ember-rails` gem.

My (ember) application consists of Models, Views, Controllers and an `application.handlebars` template which describes my UI.

**Whats the best practice to break up this `application.handlebars` file so that I can manage the UI?** For example, I'd like to have Navigation at the top of the page.

I've tried using the `Ember.Router`, a separate `navigation.handlebars`  (with NavigationView and NavigationController) the `{{outlet}}` helper to no avail. Here's what the Router looks like:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend(
  enableLogging:  true
  root: Ember.Route.extend(
    index:
      route: '/'
      connectOutlets: (router, context) =>
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navigation')
)
```

and the `application.handlebars`

```
<h1>Lots of HTML that I want to break up</h1>
{{outlet}}
```

Let me know if you need more info...thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per my Understanding, Let's suppose you want 3 sections(can be any number) Header, Content & Footer, You can do something as follows

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{view MyApp.HeaderView}}
  {{#view MyApp.ContentView}}
    {{outlet}}
  {{/view}}
  {{view MyApp.FooterView}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app-header">
  All your Header related HTML
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app-content">
  HTML related to content
  {{yield}} //this will be explained at the end
  More HTML if you want
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app-footer">
  HTML related to footer
</script>

MyApp.HeaderView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app-header'
})


MyApp.ContentView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app-content'
})

MyApp.FooterView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app-footer'
})

MyApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
})
```

explaining `{{yield}}` In a nutshell, whatever is between in the block helper of a given view goes in there, In the above example for the `MyApp.ContentView`, the `{{outlet}}` defined in the `{{#view MyApp.ContentView}}` handlebars gets inserted at the `{{yield}}`

On the similar lines let me show the difference between **layoutName** property & **templateName** property,

```
App.someView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  templateName: 'a-template',
  layoutName: 'a-container'
})

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="a-template">
  Hi There
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="a-container">
  <span class="container">
    {{yield}}
  </span>
</script>
```

Will result in following HTML

```
  <a class="ember-view" id="ember235">
    <span class="container ember-view" id="ember234">
      Hi There
    </span>
  </a>
```

Use these concepts to split the application handlebars in your case it would be something like

```
{{view App.NavigationView}}
{{outlet}}
```

## Update as per latest ember

The new ember supports `partials` similar to rails, now we can modify the above to use `{{partial}}` as follows:

```
{{partial "header"}}
{{outlet}}
{{partial "footer"}}
```

Ember when encountered this template will look for the template whose name is **_header**(similar to rails) and inserts the template(same goes for footer)

And If want to associate a controller we can use `{{render}}` helper

```
{{render "sidebar"}}
```

inserts the template whose name is **sidebar** at specified location in handlebars besides it also associates `App.SidebarController` to it,
 
**Note:** we cannot use `{{render 'sidebar'}}` more than once in same handlebars file.

But again if you want to use a widget like view multiple places in a given page then use `{{view}}` helper

Comment: This is very well explained, the key think I was missing was using the `{{view App.NavigationView}}` thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, what you need to do is think about what views change and where that changes happen. If for example you have a navigation section and a main section, then think about how each of these sections change with the state of your application. Be sure to only create an `{{outlet}}` for dynamic content, otherwise things will get messy and the application will be slower. Then setup your templates and your router similar to the example below.

**Templates:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <!--Your application template goes here-->
    {{outlet navigation}}
    {{outlet body}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navigation">
    <!--Your navigation template goes here-->
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main-one">
    <!--Your mainOne template goes here-->
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main-two">
    <!--Your mainTwo template goes here-->
</script>
```

**Note:** You can have `{{outlet}}` in any of your view templates to change in more sub-states

**Javascript:**

```
window.App = Em.Application.create({
    ApplicationView: Em.View.extend({
        templateName: "application"
    }),
    ApplicationController: Em.Controller.extend({
    }),
    NavView: Em.View.extend({
        templateName: "navigation"
    }),
    NavController: Em.Controller.extend({
    }),
    MainOneView: Em.View.extend({
        templateName: "main-one"
    }),
    MainOneController: Em.Controller.extend({
    }),
    MainTwoView: Em.View.extend({
        templateName: "main-two"
    }),
    MainTwoController: Em.Controller.extend({
    })
    Router: Em.Router.extend({
        root: Em.Route.extend({
            index: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                connectOutlets: function(router,context) {
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("navigation","nav");
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("body","mainOne");
                }
            }),
            otherState: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/other-state',
                connectOutlets: function(router,context) {
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("navigation","nav");
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("body","mainTwo");
                }
            }),

        })
    })
});
App.initialize();
```

**Note:** The applicationController must extend `Controller` and not `ObjectController` or `ArrayController`

Comment: I guess my question is more, how do I break up the static content? I don't really want all the templates stacked on the same file like that.

Comment: I have `application.handlebars` and `navigation.handlebars` in separate files, how do I combine them is the question...