# How do I automate webpage elements? (nav, footer, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a basic webpage that I built with HTML/CSS [here](http://eglove.github.io/).
However there's a few things I want to change in order to make it easier to update.

The first thing I want to do is to find a way to automate certain elements so that if I change them I don't have to go back and change it on every single page. For instance, if I add twitter to the nav on the left-column, I just want to change it once and have it universally applied across the site.

This also goes for the footer, and the share button JavaScript element that I have in the head section. (For the share buttons that appear on the left side.)

Would this be done with JavaScript? If so how?

I know how to link JavaScript files like a CSS file, but that's as far as my knowledge goes. (Besides knowing HTML, CSS and Java of course.)

Comment: have you thought about making the site in php and then using includes the header would be in 1 file that is included onto the page so if you change it in the header file it will then auto be changed on all pages the header is included

Comment: @Parody Will I have to upload before that works? I've tried it on the site with '<?php include("scripts/navigation.php"):?>' to no avail. I don't know why it wouldn't work locally but it's not. :(

Comment: "Will I have to upload before that works?". No. But you need a local server environment. Easiest way to do that is use something like MAMP or XAMPP.

Comment: @Terry http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/java/ - http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript/

Comment: No more of this syntax nonsense, this isn't the place for sandbox fighting.

Comment: @terry - Merely saying *Java* in the body of a question about Javascript does not constitute cluelessness between the two. Let's move on.

Comment: @ethan your site will all need to be in php rather than html to make full use of this functionality fully, if you tried adding it like that on a html file it wont work

Comment: With *Javascript*, you could do this with Node.js, which is of course server-side Javascript. If that's not what you mean, I would look into frameworks like Angular.js, Backbone.js with underscore.js, and Javascript template enginges like Handlebars. This is more suitable for single-page apps, though; typically, a server-side language handles basic page part includes like this. (Kind've wonder if Knockout.js also would be useful, or Ember.js.)

Comment: See [here (Angular)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286813/angularjs-handle-repeated-fragments-like-header-and-footer), [here (Angular)](http://gon.to/2013/03/23/the-right-way-of-coding-angularjs-how-to-organize-a-regular-webapp/), and [here (Handlebars)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079791/break-up-my-application-handlebars-into-separate-templates-using-ember-js-and-em). The last is probably the clearest example (and also uses Ember.js).

Comment: @Parody I created a index.php test page and put it online, the browser tries to download it, rather than view it. Googling that issues tells me that I seem to have hit the limits of GitHub static pages in that regard. :(

Comment: @JaredFarrish Much to look at, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: If you're looking for somewhere to test things out, I suggest [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). It doesn't include Ember.js (why not...), but it does allow you to use several other libraries/frameworks and emulates the "paged" format of a server directory.